# How to load parent-child relationship data using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreign-keys, amazon-rds, parent-child, aws-glue

I am  new to AWS glue, and I wanted to know the standard way to load  parent-child data from json in S3 bucket to RDS(MySQL).So let’s say we have two MySQL tables:  'user' and  'user_contact'. The ‘user’ table has the columns:  id(int) pk, auto generated values, name(varchar). And the
‘user_contact’ table has columns:  id(int) pk auto generated values, user_id(FK), address(varchar). And we have two corresponding JSON files in S3  as user.json:
[
{
"user_name": "u1"
},
{
"user_name": "u2"
},
{
"user_name": "u3"
}
]

and user_contact.json: [
{
"user_name": "u1",
"address": "adr1"
},
{
"user_name": "u2",
"address": "adr2"
},
{
"user_name": "u3",
"address": "adr3"
}
]

I want to create the AWS glue job to load  data from user.json to the table 'user' and also load user_contact.json
into the table 'user_contact'. I have created crawlers to generate source and target table in glue catalog, and the tables look fine.
But I am still unclear how to load the data using DynamicFrame via the job script. For example how to insert the PK values from 'user' table to the
FK values in the 'user_contact' table dynamically was my main hurdle. Please let me know the pseudo-code for the job(critical steps for the transformation).

The job will finally populate the data into tables as follows:

### user

#id      #name

1         u1

2         u2

3         u3

### user_contact

#id  #user_id      #address

```
1      1            adr1

2      2            adr2

3      3            adr3
```

Comment: So basically I was able to create that job. I first populated the parent table (user) as I saved the dynamicframe in it. Then I created the a new dynamicframe using that as a source, and joined this frame with the user_contact frame using (name,user_name). Now in that frame we have the primary key values, but these are in 'id' field. Now I renamed 'id' to 'user_id' as it is the FK column in the user_contact table. Then I selected fields to match the user_contact catalog table, and wrote the dynamic frame to the target catalog table , and it worked. Is this the correct way?.

Comment: handle_009, see if you could put your solution as an answer with sample code? It would be very helpful.